# Segfault in pytorch on M1: torch.from_numpy(X).float()

Tags: pytorch, segmentation-fault, apple-m1

I'm using an M1.

I'm trying to use pytorch for a conv net.

I have a numpy array that I'm trying to turn into a torch tensor.

When I call

`torch.from_numpy(X)`

pytorch throws an error that it got a double when it expected a float.

When I call

`torch.from_numpy(X).float()` on a friends computer, everything is fine.

But when I call this command on my computer, I get a segfault.

Has anyone seen this / know what might be happening / know how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

What's your pytorch vision? I've encountered the same problem on my Macbook Pro M1, and my pytorch version is 1.12.0 at first. The I downgraded it to version 1.10.0 and the problem is solved. I suspect this has something to do with the compatibility with M1 in newer torch versions.

Actually I first uninstalled torch using `pip3 uninstall torch` and then reinstalled with `pip3 install torch==1.10.0`

But if you are using torchvision or some other affiliated packages, you may also need to downgrade them too.